nginx Memory footprint Big
enter image description here
My configuration file is only 5m, but look at the memory footprint, memory loaded nginx.conf, almost 3GB, and why so many processes have such a high footprint.
try Modify the configuration file    ,I want to know why so much memory is occupied and why the configuration file is not so large and whyyour text it can take up so much memory.
